# Linear regression & exponential data

Tags: statistics, linear-transformations, exponential-function, regression, linear-regression

I am taking a applied stats course and we just started transforming in linear regression. If you could just look at the question below and explain it in general terms that you be incredibly helpful. Thank you.

Because the units of log leaf number can be hard to interpret biologically, I want to produce
a finished graph that still has a curve and has axes labeled with the original units, so as not
to mislead the readers into thinking that the original data are linear.

However, I want to incorporate the info that I calculated from my linear regression model for
the slope of the curve line on the graphic. How would I do this? What values would I need
to transform or back-transform in order to do this and what would these new values be?

The linear regression for this was found to be y = 4.46 + .3486 (x)

Comment: What is your original function, probably $y=a\cdot b^x$?

Comment: Yes, it was. And it was transformed into a linear equation and then graphed.

Comment: Have a look at this example, where $y_=\gamma\cdot e^{\beta \cdot G_i}$  is equivalent to $y=a\cdot b^x$. The crucial point is that the $y$-values has to be transformed in to $\ln (y)$-values.